# bind nsrect and nstextfield

Tags: macos, cocoa, operating-system

I would like to bind frame of NSView to model property NSRect. I did this in that way:

```
[textView.enclosingScrollView bind:@"frame" toObject:bindingsController withKeyPath:@"selection.textFrame" options:nil];
```

But I also would like to bind frame.origin.x to nstextField. How to do it, with NSValueTransformer?

Answer (score 0):

You can only bind to a property, which means you cannot bind to a certain part of the frame directly. You could do it indirectly either by binding to the frame and using a transformer to get just the x coordinate, or you could add a property to your view which accesses the frame and returns the x coordinate. I would suggest the second method, since you can do it using a category instead of a subclass, and it is easier to allow setting the value.

```
@interface NSView (FrameXCoordinate)
@property (nonatomic) double frameXCoordinate;
@end

@implementation NSView (FrameXCoordinate)

- (double)frameXCoordinate {
    return [self frame].origin.x;
}
- (void)setFrameXCoordinate:(double)x {
    NSRect frame = [self frame];
    frame.origin.x = x;
    [self setFrame:frame];
}

@end
```

Using this, you would simply bind to the `frameXCoordinate` property and add a number formatter to your text field.